# python applying different conditions to a while loop output

Tags: python

Ok so I have this function that takes 3 arguments which are lists.
and then depending on the order that the lists are fed into the function,
the function mix's them together to create a new list.

I also have a lists of lists called "sets" which are the 3 orders that I want to mix my lists together.

Then I have a while loop which I am feeding my sets into.

However this is where things get tricky.
I also have 3 prints,
and as my loop runs 3 times, I would like to apply only one print to each loop.

So far I have tried to store my prints into a list of there own but am unable as some of the variables only exist within the loop

```
def mix(a,b,c):
  d,e,f = iter(a), iter(b), iter(c)
  result = [item for sublist in zip(d,e,f) for item in sublist]
  result += [item for item in d]
  result += [item for item in e]
  result += [item for item in f]
  return result

a = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
b = ['a','b','c','d','e']
c = ['1','2','3','4','5']

sets =  [[a,b,c],[b,c,a],[c,a,b]]

q = 0
while q < len(sets):
  a = sets[q][0]
  b = sets[q][1]
  c = sets[q][2]
  d = a[::-1]
  e = b[::-1]
  f = c[::-1]

  print(mix(a,b,c)) # first loop only
  print(mix(d,e,f)) # second loop only
  print(mix(a,e,c)) # third loop only

  q+=1
```

I have also tried adding blank lists but I didnt achive the expected outcome.

```
def mix(a,b,c):
  d,e,f = iter(a), iter(b), iter(c)
  result = [item for sublist in zip(d,e,f) for item in sublist]
  result += [item for item in d]
  result += [item for item in e]
  result += [item for item in f]
  return result

a = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
b = ['a','b','c','d','e']
c = ['1','2','3','4','5']
d=[]
e=[]
f=[]

sets =  [[a,b,c],[b,c,a],[c,a,b]]
outputs = [mix(a,b,c),mix(d,e,f),mix(a,e,c)]

q = 0

while q < len(sets):

  a = sets[q][0]
  b = sets[q][1]
  c = sets[q][2]
  d = a[::-1]
  e = b[::-1]
  f = c[::-1]

  print(outputs[q])

  q+=1
```

Expected output:

```
['A', 'a', '1', 'B', 'b', '2', 'C', 'c', '3', 'D', 'd', '4', 'E', 'e', '5']
['e', '5', 'E', 'd', '4', 'D', 'c', '3', 'C', 'b', '2', 'B', 'a', '1', 'A']
['1', 'E', 'a', '2', 'D', 'b', '3', 'C', 'c', '4', 'B', 'd', '5', 'A', 'e']
```

Comment: So `if q==0` do the first `print`, `if q==1` do the second, otherwise do the third?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @scott Hunter, yes that is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @guy updated question to include expected output

Comment: @jessyjack did you try @Scott's solution? a simple `if else` block should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott Hunter suggest, you can include your print statement in `if else` and your while loop became:

```
while q < len(sets):
  a = sets[q][0]
  b = sets[q][1]
  c = sets[q][2]
  d = a[::-1]
  e = b[::-1]
  f = c[::-1]
  if q == 0:
    print(mix(a,b,c)) # first loop only
  elif q == 1:
    print(mix(d,e,f)) # second loop only
  else:    
    print(mix(a,e,c)) # third loop only

  q+=1
```

Hopefully this is the expected output:

```
['A', 'a', '1', 'B', 'b', '2', 'C', 'c', '3', 'D', 'd', '4', 'E', 'e', '5']
['e', '5', 'E', 'd', '4', 'D', 'c', '3', 'C', 'b', '2', 'B', 'a', '1', 'A']
['1', 'E', 'a', '2', 'D', 'b', '3', 'C', 'c', '4', 'B', 'd', '5', 'A', 'e']
```